# How to connect to PostgreSQL with my default windows username

Tags: postgresql, authentication, psql

I read already multiple posts, where they had trouble connecting to the postgres default user.

However, in my case I can connect to user `postgres` without a problem, but I can't login with my default windows user. When I use the SQL Shell it just logs me into the postgres user.

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]: maximilian
Password for user maximilian:
psql (12.1)
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#         ----> As you can see still logged in as postgres user
```

I am set up as a user in postgres as shown below:

```
postgres=# \du
                                    List of roles
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 maximilian | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

If I want to use the CMD command prompt `psql` - Default user is `Maximilian` and returns an error when entering my password.

```
C:\Users\Maximilian>psql --help

Connection options:
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory (default: "local socket")
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port (default: "5432")
  -U, --username=USERNAME  database user name (default: "Maximilian")
  -w, --no-password        never prompt for password
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)

psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Maximilian"
```

`psql` already recognized `Maximilian` as default user before I created that role/user `maximilian`  in postgres.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case matters in PostgreSQL, even though SQL is case folded unless quoted.

The database user is `maximilian`, but the operating system user is `Maximilian`.

You could rename the user:

```
ALTER ROLE maximilian RENAME TO "Maximilian";
```

But "quoted", mixed-case identifiers are a truly bad idea.

So I suggest that you set the environment variable `PGUSER` to `maximilian`, then that will be the default username.

By the way: the `postgres` in your `psql` prompt is not the username, but the database you are connected to.